# Heroku deployment failed yet the build has passed

Tags: python, django

I am facing this error on Heroku but I don't know the issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

But my requirements.txt file is fine :

```
asgiref==3.6.0
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
dj-database-url==1.2.0
Django==3.2
django-bunny-storage==0.1.2
django-countries==7.5.1
django-extensions==3.2.1
django-phone-auth==0.3.1
django-phonenumber-field==7.0.2
django-storages==1.13.2
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
google-api-core==2.11.0
google-auth==2.17.3
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-storage==2.8.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.10
isort==5.12.0
phonenumbers==8.13.5
Pillow==9.4.0
protobuf==4.22.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.5
pyasn1==0.5.0
pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
pycountry==22.3.5
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.15.0
pytz==2022.7.1
requests==2.28.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
twilio==6.63.2
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.12
uuid==1.30
whitenoise==6.4.0
```

Here's my Procfile :

```
web: gunicorn pixsar.wsgi --log-file -
release: python manage.py migrate
```

and my gitlab.yml :

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.25.4
  entrypoint: [""]

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

stages:
  - deploy-stag

deploy-stag:
  stage: deploy-stag
  image: ruby:latest
  before_script:
    - gem install dpl
    - wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
  script:
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    - export HEROKU_API_KEY=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    - heroku run --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME python manage.py migrate
    - heroku run --app $HEROKU_APP_NAME python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
  only:
    - develop
```

What is wrong here

Comment: Are you sure that it is supposed to be  `Django` and not `django` in the `requirements.txt` ?

Comment: When I pip freeze, it says `Django` @Lanfix

Comment: My bad, looks like its normal. Then maybe it didn't install the requirements

Comment: It actually has the requirement, I checked in the console